# how to show my post only to my friends in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to show my post only to my friends, How can I filter my post only to my friends? I have tried to filter in html code but as my friends get more, it repeats my post more (I mean repeat one post few times )
My models.py

```
class PostUser(models.Model):
    posttype        = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='postuser')
    content         = models.TextField(null = True, blank= True)
    media_image     = models.FileField(null = True, blank= True)
    media_video     = models.FileField(null = True, blank= True)
    per_to          = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True, default='everyone')
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='active')
    date            = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    time            = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    datetime        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    like            = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    comment         = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    share           = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_pk         = models.IntegerField()




class Friends(models.Model):
    # Sender
    friend_one      = models.IntegerField()

    # Reciver
    friend_two      = models.IntegerField()
    
    per_to          = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True, default='everyone')
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='active')
    datetime        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date            = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    time            = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and this is my views.py

```
allmyfriends     = Friends.objects.filter(Q(friend_one = request.user.pk) | Q(friend_two = request.user.pk))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ramin Zamani- Your friend model is messed up. Have a look at this.

Rename your model Friends to UserFriend. It's a model that shows the relation between 2 entities - The user and his/her friends/followers. The model name shouldn't be plural.

```
from django.conf import settings
class UserFriend(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    friend = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
     ................
```

Also, I could have used a many-to-many relation but I prefer the foreign key relation. It's up to your preference.

Your post model needs to be fixed

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_by= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    ...............
```

And if you want only specific users to let's say view a post then you can do the following.
in your views.py

```
 post = Post.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs.get('name')) 
  #to check if the user trying to access the post is a friend of the postcreator user.
  friend = UserFriend.objects.get(user=post.created_by,friend=self.request.user)
  if friend:
        render()
  else:
       return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: After changing how can I show my post only to my friends?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like :-

**models.py**

```
Choices = (
    (True,'Friends can see  Post'),
    (False,'Friends cannot see Post'),
)


class Friends(models.Model):
    ...................
    only_friends = models.BooleanField(max_length=30,choices=Choices,default=True)
```

Accessing Friends model objects in `views` Because our `BooleanField` is in `Friends model` so we have to access Friends model first to access `only_friends BooleanField`

```
def some_view(request,user_id):
    allmyfriends = get_object_or_404(Friends,user_user_id)
    p = request.user
    you = p.user
    friends = p.friends.all()

    context = {'allmyfriends':allmyfriends,'friends':friends}
    return render(request, 'mains:your_template.html', context}
```

**urls.py**

```
path('some_view/<int:user_id>/',views.some_view,name='some_view'),
```

**your_template.html**

Now do work carefully here.

In showing post, I assume that you're using loop for showing all of users Post. like :-

```
{% for posts in post %}

 {% if posts.user.only_friends == True and posts.user in request.user.friends.all %}

    {{ post.posttype }}

 {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

**Note :- This FrontEnd will only work after you set your PostUser ForeignKey relationship with User like** :-

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PostUser(models.Model):
    ..................
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
```

**Also Set your Friends model ForeignKey RelationShip with User**

```
class Friends(models.Model):
    .............
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
```

**Explanation :-**

In models.py :- I add a BooleanField with Choices.

In views.py :- I access Friends model to access its objects with user_id. ( Check carefully in template urls while using user_id )

In template :- I use a `for loop` to show `all` the Posts. AND In for loop i started `if` statement that If the user who posted a post is in `request.user`'s friends and have BooleanField `True` then Post will show and if request.user is`not` in posted user then the post will not be shown.

Comment: if my friends want to see my post from home then how should I write my views.py

Comment: I've tried getting some problem, trying to fix the problem, I think because i have changed to ForeignKey, other query from different views give me problem

Comment: Did you set `ForeignKey Relationship` with both the models ?

Comment: yes I did, that's why now i'm getting problem

Comment: I'm getting error because I have changed to ForeignKey, sow I think for calling them from model i have to change my query

Comment: I know you getting Error BUT Can you  tell which is that error ?

Comment: tripchizapp.Friends.friend_two: (fields.E307) The field tripchizapp.Friends.friend_two was declared with a lazy reference to 'tripchizapp.user', but app 'tripchizapp' doesn't provide model 'user'.

Comment: Did you import `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` in models.py ?

Comment: Is your code at `Github` ? If Yes then please provide a link to it, So i can see it.

Comment: No, It's not on 'Github'

Comment: Then, How can i see your Code ?

Comment: I have another question, I'm trying to make hashtag, I get hashtag and save it in db but now I wanna make it hyperlink, do you know how can I do that?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250859/how-can-make-hashtag-clickable-and-show-it-in-the-post-in-django   this is the link for my question

Comment: I try to upload it on github and sent you a link