# how can make hashtag clickable and show it in the post in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

User can make hashtag. Now I want to make hashtag clickable. Bellow is my Models.py for Hashtag:

```
class Hashtag(models.Model):
    hashtagname     = models.CharField(max_length=3000, blank=True, null=True)
    hashtagcount    = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    post_pk         = models.ManyToManyField(PostUser)
    atetime         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date            = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    time            = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_pk         = models.IntegerField()
```

and in my views.py I get all the hashtags and send it by dictionary to html as bellow codes:

```
mosttrending     = Hashtag.objects.all().order_by('-hashtagcount')[:10]
```

and already I have a model for all the Posts as bellow

```
class PostUser(models.Model):
    posttype        = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='postuser')
    content         = models.TextField(null = True, blank= True)
    media_image     = models.FileField(null = True, blank= True)
    media_video     = models.FileField(null = True, blank= True)
    per_to          = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True, default='everyone')
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=3000, default='active')
    date            = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    time            = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    datetime        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    like            = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    comment         = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    share           = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_pk         = models.IntegerField()
```

And in my html with a for loop I get all the PostUser:

```
{% for readposts in readposts %}
<p class="card-text">{{readposts.content|linebreaks}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

How Can I make the link for hashtag and when a user click on the hashtag show the user the all the post?

Comment: Do you want to show all the tags or Only posts that are containing that the Tag you clicked ?

Comment: I want to show all the post that has hashtag or tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made app_extras.py and **init**.py in a folder name templatetags in my django app then in the app_extras.py wrote the code bellow and worked

```
import re
from django import template
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

def create_hashtag_link(tag):
    url = "/tags/{}/".format(tag)
    # or: url = reverse("hashtag", args=(tag,))
    return '<a href="{}">#{}</a>'.format(url, tag)


@register.filter(name='hashchange')
def hashtag_links(value):
    return mark_safe(
        re.sub(r"#(\w+)", lambda m: create_hashtag_link(m.group(1)),
               escape(value)))
```

then in HTML I have loaded the app_extras.py

```
{% load app_extras %}
```

Then in my loop html I called the function

```
{% for readposts in readposts %}
<p class="card-text">{{readposts.content|hashchange|linebreaks}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

and also my urls.py I have added

```
url(r'^tags/(?P<tags>\w+)/$', views.tags, name='tags'),
```

then of course a view for tag which in this case my view is

```
def tags(request, tags):
      readpostsuser   = PostUser.objects.filter(content__icontains = tags).order_by('-pk')

return render(request, 'front/tags.html', {'readpostsuser':readpostsuser})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a hyperlink?

```
{% for readposts in readposts %}
<p class="card-text"> <a href='/putyourlinkhere?hashtag= 
{{readposts.content|linebreaks}}'>{{readposts.content|linebreaks}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

In views.py:

```
myhashtag = request.GET.get('hashtag')
```

request.GET.get gets the 'hashtag' variable from the link and and saves it to myhashtag variable.

then you can perform a query to search for myhashtag and return the info.

Comment: {% for readposts in readposts %}
<p class="card-text"> <a href='/putyourlinkhere?hashtag= 
{{readposts.content|linebreaks}}'>{{readposts.content|linebreaks}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}  it makes hole the output as a link but i don't want to make all as a link, just hashtag should be link

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :-

**views.py**

put this in your working view :-

```
query = request.GET.gel('q')   
object_list = PostUser.objects.filter(hashtag__hashtagname__icontains=query)

context = {'object_list ':object_list}
```

**template**

template where you've done all your view work

```
{% for tags in object_list %}


{{ tags }}

{{ tags.hashtagname }}

{% endfor %}
```

**Note** :- This is not clickable. I want you to try this First.

Comment: I'm getting '  Cannot resolve keyword 'hashtagname' into field. Choices are: comment, content, date, datetime, hashtag, id, like, media_image, media_video, per_to, posttype, share, status, time, user_pk '

Comment: I found the answer and I it's bellow this post, Thanks Program